# Calculating the $p+1$ derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, induction

I'm stucked with the following:

> Let $y\in C^1(I),f\in C^p(I\times R,R)$,$k\in C^p(I\times I,R)$, $f$ is Lipschitz and such that
>   $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t))+g(t)$$
>   where
>   $$g(t)= \int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s\qquad y(t_0)=y_0$$
>   Prove that $y\in C^{p+1}$

I see that I only have to prove that $\eta\in C^p$ when
 $$\eta(t):=\int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
I tried to prove it by induction, but I fail to see what I should assume to be true for the $p=n$, since I don't know the formula for the $n$-derivative.

If $p=1$

\begin{align*}
\eta^{p}(t)&=k(t,t)y(t) +\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} k(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s\\
&=k(t,t)y(t)+\int_{t_0}^t k_t(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s
\end{align*}
Now what should I do now? If anyone could give me a hint maybe?

Comment: Is it for homework or curious about it or...?

Comment: @RafaBudría homework & curious :)

Comment: If you want I can try, but I think you have almost it all: the idea of induction (you have proved the first case) and you seem to know that the Leibniz rule is the point for the induction step. You need some creativity defining things, e.g. the sum of functions you get by the iterated use of the derivative and the Leibniz rule.

Comment: @RafaBudría So I first need to find as series for $n$ and then make the induction step?

Comment: Yes. Make your way derivating two, three times and see two things, the form the series take and that each step "makes" $y$ differentiable once more time. You have too to follow the path to $f$. In each derivative you have not to calculate explicitly the derivative of the product, simply name it with some subindex or so.

Comment: @RafaBudría two things confuse me. First I have once the partial derivative $k_t(t,s)$ and another time the "real" $k'(t,t)$ is that correct? Second I come across $y''$ when I compute $\eta'''$ but I don't know if $y''$ exists (isn't that kinda what I have to prove?)
$$\eta''(t)=k'(t,t)y(t)+k(t,t)y'(t))+k_t(t,t)y(t)+\int_{t_0}^t k_t(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56194/discussion-between-rafa-budria-and-waldorozir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))+\int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$ and the initial hypothesis of $y'$, $f^{p}$, $k_{x^p}$ and $k_{y^p}$ being continuous. We can prove that $y''$ is continuous too.

$$k_1(u,v)=k(u,v)$$

$$y''(t)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f(t,y(t))+k_1(t,t)y(t) +\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} k_1(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

Is continuos because $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f(t,y(t))$ is the derivative of a composition of functions with continuous derivatives and $k_1$ has partial derivatives continuous.

$$k_2(u,v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u} k_1(u,v)$$

$$y'''(t)=\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dt^2}f(t,y(t))+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(k_1(t,t)y(t)) +k_2(t,t)y(t)+\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} k_2(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

Is continuous because is the sum of functions or its derivatives of functions with at least its second derivatives continuous.

Now, define,

$$k_n(u,v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u} k_{n-1}(u,v)$$

Consider this formula for the $(n+1)$-th derivative of $y$

$$y^{(n+1)}(t)=\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dt^n}f(t,y(t))+\sum_2^{n}\frac{\mathrm d^{i-1}}{\mathrm dt^{i-1}}(k_{n-i+1}(t,t)y(t)) + k_n(t,t)y(t)+\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} k_{n}(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

Differentiate once more time:

$$y^{(n+2)}(t)=\frac{\mathrm d^{n+1}}{\mathrm dt^{n+1}}f(t,y(t))+\sum_2^{n}\frac{\mathrm d^{i}}{\mathrm dt^{i}}(k_{n-i+1}(t,t)y(t)) + \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}k_n(t,t)y(t)+k_{n+1}(t,t)y(t)+\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} k_{n+1}(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

$$y^{(n+2)}(t)=\frac{\mathrm d^{n+1}}{\mathrm dt^{n+1}}f(t,y(t))+\sum_2^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm d^{i-1}}{\mathrm dt^{i-1}}(k_{n+1-i+1}(t,t)y(t))+k_{n+1}(t,t)y(t)+\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} k_{n+1}(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

So, the formula holds for $n+1$ if it holds for $n$ and, too, if $y$ has its $n+1\le p$ derivative continuous, it has derivative $n+2$ continuous.

Now, set $n+1=p$ and it's proved.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the time!